# Selenium chrome driver version doesn't matching

Tags: python, selenium

I am new in python and I got this error when I am trying to open a website with Selenium

> **This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 88
> Current browser version is 90.0.4430.93 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe**

someone know how do I fix this?

Comment: Just beware that you could run into this about once per month unless you disable auto-updates in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your chromedriver:

v1. If you installed the chromedriver with the command `pip install chromedriver` then run in a terminal: `pip install chromedriver-py==90.0.4430.24`

v2. If you downloaded chromedriver manually. First kill all processes chromedriver.exe from the taskmanager and then find where you have the chromedriver.exe and replace it with the 90 version of it from here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=90.0.4430.24/