# Selenium ChromeDriver Version Conflict

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver

My Selenium program written with Ruby randomly stopped working (it ran perfectly yesterday) and gave me this error:

`Backtrace:: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)Current browser version is 91.0.4472.77 with binary path C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe`

I've since tried:

- Un & re-installing ChromeDriver (newest version, as I was using before)
- Replacing my current version with version 89 along with changing the path (this resulted in the same error)
- Following these similar issues [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345289/selenium-chrome-driver-version-doesnt-matching) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479989/chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-89)

I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: I'd also like to add that when I run chromedriver.exe cmd prompt is opened displaying this information:

Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.19 (1bf021f248676a0b2ab3ee0561d83a59e424c23e-refs/branch-heads/4472@{#288}) on port 9515

Comment: I figured out how to fix this problem but I'm not going to post it as an answer because I don't quite know why this fixed it. I removed Chromedriver from my System Path and moved chromedriver.exe into C:\Ruby27-x64\bin. I've never done this before and selenium-chromedriver worked perfectly fine until as of late so, again, I have no idea why this worked but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently with the C# version.

I would double check where Selenium is being ran from.

In my case it was `debug/netcoreapp3.1\chromedriver.exe`, so it was running an outdated version compared to the version of Chrome installed.

Make sure you have the correct ChromeDriver version from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

If this fails, check the Ruby bindings wiki [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings)

Comment: This is the common issue when browser version get change you need to change your driver. To solve this we can use the WebDriver manager. There is bonigarcia WebDriver Manager which identifies your browser version and download the driver accordingly.  for more detail please flow the link: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in C#. I had to update Nugget for `ChromeDriver` to match versions. So I basically updated my `ChromeDriver` to `91.0.4472` and it's resolved the issue.